# IBM MQ JMS selector using a list of values

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm encountering a situation for which I can't find any other examples on the Internet, and I was wondering if anyone had any idea about this.

Basically, we need to use a selector a Spring `JmsListener` which looks for the value in a list of strings we defined in the `.yml` file. I saw examples in the IBM documentation which look like this

> Country IN ('UK', 'US', 'France') is true for 'UK' and false for 'Peru'. It is equivalent to the expression (Country = 'UK') OR (Country = 'US') OR (Country = 'France').

But we need to load them from the `.yml` file. So far, we tried like this

```java
@Value("${jms.selector}") 
String selectors;
....
@JmsListener(destination = ... , container = ... , selector = "channel IN (${jms.selector})")
```

and the property in the `.yml` file looks like this

```
jms:
  selector: TYPE1, TYPE2
```

But we get the following error

```
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination '...' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue '...'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ cqll failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2459' ('MQRC_SELECTOR_SYNTAX_ERROR')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the single quotes around the literal strings in the selector. The following would be a valid selector.

```
"channel IN ('TYPE1','TYPE2')"
```

Comment: I saw that, but if I'm taking the strings from the .yml file, how could I do it?
I tried with
- 'TYPE1'
-'TYPE2'
but we still get the same error

Comment: I'm not a Spring expert, so I'd be inclined to get the selector @Value into a String or String[] and display it. It will probably need to be manipulated to get it in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting a list / array of strings so need:

```
@Value("${jms.selector}") 
String[] selectors;
```

`selectors` will be: `["UK","US","France"]`

Once you have that you can convert it into single string of comma separated quoted strings

```
String selectorString = "'" + String.join("','", selectors); + "'"
```

`selectorString` will be: `"'UK','US','France'"`